# What does Google mean by "recently released apps"?

Tags: google-play-store

Google lets users browse recently released apps via
https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/topselling_new_free

How does Google define recently released? Does that actually mean recently updated apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that it's a marketing term and is purposely not defined. In fact, there's probably no defined date cutoff at all; it's probably the latest X number of apps sorted by most recent release date (that also meet some other criteria).

We also can't know if the list is manually manipulated.

So, I think the only people who can answer this work at Google, and they're not telling.

Answer (score 3):

> Does that actually mean recently updated apps?

It does state "New" in the title so it would be misleading if it also included apps that had been solely updated. That would also be a lot less helpful. Presumably this page is to help new apps be discovered.

The first 3 rows of apps on the page you link to (27 total) have all been updated in the last month, most in the last couple of weeks. The handful I looked at further were also *new* in that time, judging by the dates of the first reviews.

> Top New ....

These are also the "top" new apps so I suspect they must also have seen a sufficiently high *rate* of installs, ratings and Google+ recommendations.

Most of these have 1000's of reviews, although curiously [Peppa Pig jigsaw puzzle](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pepa.jigsaw.puzzle.kids) "only" has 58, although an average rating of 4/5 and 50,000 - 100,000 installs and 300 Google+ recommendations. And that appears to be in just 1 week.